# PHP string in hexadecimal format strange result

Tags: php

I have the following code which produces different result in different PHP version. Am I missing something or is it a bug in PHP 7.1.24 or there some kind of PHP setting which could affect this?

```
<?php
$a = "\x43\xbe\xb7\xe8\x30\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00";
$b = "\x4b\x40";
$c = $a . $b;


echo strlen($a) . "<br>";
echo strToHex($a) . "<br>";

echo strlen($b) . "<br>";
echo strToHex($b) . "<br>";

echo strlen($c) . "<br>";
echo strToHex($c) . "<br>";

function strToHex($string) {
    $hex = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }

    return $hex;
}
```

PHP 7.1.24 Output:

```
8
43beb7e8300100

2
4b40

10
43beb7e830010000
```

Desired result: **PHP 5.6.40, PHP 7.1.27, PHP 7.2.16, 7.3.3**

```
10
43beb7e830010000

2
4b40

12
43beb7e8300100004b40
```

**Example #2**

```
<?php
$a = "\xe8\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5";

echo strlen($a) . "<br>";
echo strToHex($a) . "<br>";

$b = array(
    "\xe8",
    "\xf1",
    "\xf2",
    "\xf3",
    "\xf4",
    "\xf5"
);
$b = implode("", $b);

echo strlen($b) . "<br>";
echo strToHex($b) . "<br>";

function strToHex($string) {
    $hex = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }

    return $hex;
}
```

**Wrong result:**

```
2
e8f1
2
e8f1
```

**Good result:**

```
6
e8f1f2f3f4f5
6
e8f1f2f3f4f5
```

Comment: Doesn't reproduce…?! https://3v4l.org/p2mDa

Comment: Output is consistent across all versions here, https://3v4l.org/gsYIU Guess: Probably different settings regarding multibyte string functionality.

Comment: I can confirm that I wasn't able to reproduce with that tool. But it happens on a server and I'm not sure what to check...

Comment: Compare the php.ini settings/`phpinfo()`.

Comment: I checked and there was nothing strange in phpinfo(). https://jsfiddle.net/kbm1rphc/1/
Just updated the question with another example which clearly shows that something messed up inside PHP. PHP doc states that strings are stored as raw bytes without encoding, but still some kind of encoding applied.